# Making forum data publicly available

Tags: united-states, data-ownership

I administrate an Internet forum that is available to anyone who register to it (and anyone may register).

Can I legally create a dump of the forum data and share it publicly? The dump would only contain, for each post: username, timestamp, post title and post body.

Comment: Does the forum have a ToS that people agree to when they register?

Comment: @Christian  No ToS.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.